# Can't login to Jenkins behind Kerberos

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jenkins, kerberos

I have kerberos setup on a series of machines and cannot login to a default deployment of Jenkins.  My backend configuration looks like the following:

```
firewall.local (CentOS 7)
apache.local (CentOS 7)
tomcat.local (CentOS 7, Tomcat 7, Oracle JDK 7)
```

firewall.local forwards requests on 80 to apache.local.  apache.local has AJP setup to tomcat.local

All webapp's work fine.  I have them protected by a kerberos login being surfaced by apache.

The problem is when I try to hit firewall.local/jenkins (internally this ends up being routed all the way to tomcat.local:8009/jenkins).  I get a dialog asking for my username and password for Kerberos.  This works.  Then I'm prompted with a dialog box for Jenkins.

I've tried several kerberos and non-kerberos combinations and they always fail resulting in continus prompts for user names and passwords.

Is there a default username and password for Jenkins?  Is there something I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that Jenkins setup has changed.  I had to first go through the wizard which first asked for a password located at

```
/opt/tomcat/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

After the wizard compelted and setup my user I was able to login.